# simplifying trace of product of two unitary operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics, matrix-exponential

For Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, diagonalizing each unitary matrix $e^{iA}$ and $e^{iB}$ gives

\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}(e^{iA}e^{iB}) = \text{Tr}(U^* e^{iD_A}UV^*e^{iD_B}V),
\end{equation} where $D_A$ and $D_B$ are diagonal matrices of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then, by using cyclic property of trace and defining a new unitary operator $X = UV^*$, the above equation equals to

\begin{equation}
= \text{Tr}(X^* e^{iD_A}X e^{iD_B}).
\end{equation} Choosing a complete orthonormal basis set $\{\lvert i \rangle\}$ (using [braket-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation)) and another complete orthonormal basis set $\{\lvert j \rangle\}$  that includes $\lvert i \rangle$, we further have
\begin{equation}
= \sum_i \langle i \rvert X^* e^{iD_A}X e^{iD_B}\lvert i \rangle = \sum_i\langle i \rvert X^* e^{iD_A}X  \big(\sum_j \lvert j \rangle \langle j\big) \rvert e^{iD_B}\lvert i \rangle = \sum_i\langle i \rvert X^* e^{iD_A}X  \lvert i\rangle\cdot  e^{iD_{B,i}},
\end{equation} where $D_{B,i}$ is $i$th element of the diagonal matrix $D_B$, i.e. $i$th eigenvalue, and I used the fact that $\langle{j}\rvert e^{iD_B} \lvert{i}\rangle = 0$ if $j \neq i$. Since $X$ is a unitary operator, we can absorb it to the exponent, i.e. $X^* e^{iD_A}X = e^{iX^*D_AX}$. Moreover, applying $X^*$ and $X$ to $D_A$ won't change the eigenvalues (diagonal elements) of $D_A$, but permutes the ordering of diagonal elements of $D_A$. Denoting this permutation by $p(i)$, we finally have

\begin{equation}
= \sum_i e^{iD_{A,p(i)}}\cdot e^{iD_{B,i}}.
\end{equation}

However, numerics tell me that my equation is wrong. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that certainly makes this confusing is that you're mixing bra-ket notation (coordinate free/basis independent) with matrix representations (basis dependent notation). It doesn't really make sense to "diagonalize" when using bra-ket notation, just use the eigen-basis to calculate the trace.

Assuming $B$ is a self adjoint operator, it seems like what you want is to say that $\{\lvert i\rangle\}$ is the eigen-basis of $B$, i.e. $B\lvert i\rangle=\lambda_i\lvert i \rangle$. In which case

$$\langle m \lvert e^{iB}\rvert n\rangle=\delta_{mn}e^{i\lambda_n}$$

Then your trace becomes

$$\begin{align}
\text{Tr}\left(e^{iA}e^{iB}\right)&=\sum\limits_{i,j}\langle i \lvert e^{iA}\rvert j\rangle \langle j \lvert e^{iB}\rvert i\rangle\\
&=\sum\limits_j \langle j \lvert e^{iA}\rvert j\rangle e^{i\lambda_j}
\end{align}$$

Notice that we don't know anything about $\langle j \lvert e^{iA}\rvert j\rangle$ since the eigen-basis we chose was that of $B$ not of $A$. So unless $A$ and $B$ commute (in which case they share an orthonormal eigen-basis and $e^{iA} e^{iB}=e^{i(A+B)}$) then the expression cannot simplify any further until the action of $A$ on the eigen-basis of $B$ is specified.

In your attempt one thing that was incorrect was that you said that applying $X^*$ and $X$ on $D_A$ would permute the eigenvalues, this is incorrect in general $X^* D_A X$ need not be diagonal at all.

Hope this helps